# Initating variables in Python

Tags: python

```
class Grid:
    def __init__(self, cellNum, cellData):
        self.cellNum, self.cellData = cellNum, cellData
```

I am new to python and wondering if there is any more clearer way to write this?  I am trying to solve a nonogram and therefore needs to understand this part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can break up the initialisation line, but I think the code can't get clearer than that:

```
class Grid:
    def __init__(self, cellNum, cellData):
        self.cellNum = cellNum
        self.cellData = cellData
```

Comment: Oh, that easy. Thank you. I feel dumb now. It was just so confusing the way it was written.

Comment: @BjornarRemmen Don't feel dumb. You've learned something. In fact, you should feel smarter.